# Formatting JQuery DataTables Data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a JQuery DataTable that I am populating with data from MySQL.  The DataTable displays as expected, but I need a few changes made.  How can I **ONLY** set the 'Attempts' And 'Completes' to a hyperlink if the value is <> 0.  And also, how can I capture the 'SalesRep' name from the selected column?  (I'm going to pass that to the opening page to show specific data for that 'SalesRep'.

This is the code that I have.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Manager</th>
                    <th>SalesRep</th>
                    <th># Doors Knocked</th>
                    <th># Sales Made</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var information = <?php echo json_encode($salesinfo) ?>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').salesinfoTable({
            salesinfo: information,
            columns: [
                { salesinfo: 'Manager' },
                { salesinfo: 'SalesRep' },
                { 
                   salesinfo: 'Attempts' ,
                   render: function(salesinfo, type, row, meta) {
                       if(type == 'display') {
                           salesinfo = '<a href="' + salesinfo + '">' + salesinfo + '</a>';
                       }
                       return salesinfo;
                   }
                },
                { 
                    salesinfo: 'Completes',
                    render: function(salesinfo, type, row, meta) {
                       if(type == 'display') {
                           salesinfo = '<a href="' + salesinfo + '">' + salesinfo + '</a>';
                       }
                       return salesinfo;
                   }     
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**
I tried to use your updated code of

```
if(data != 0)
```

But when I do that I get an error in the console of:

```
Uncaught Error: DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'Attempts' for row 0, column 2. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
    at K (jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=2.3.4:74)
    at B (jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=2.3.4:17)
    at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=2.3.4:25)
    at O (jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=2.3.4:16)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=2.3.4:92)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=2.3.4:93)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.n [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=2.3.4:83)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):251)
```

This is an example of my data that I am using, the last two values are the ones that I am wanting to ONLY hyperlink if they are >= 1

```
var data = [
    { "Manager": "M1", "SalesRep": "Rep1", "Attempts": "0", "Completes": "1" }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** Fixed some code and added snippet sample

**UPDATED:** changed validation inside example code

> How can I ONLY set the 'Attempts' And 'Completes' to a hyperlink if
>   the value is <> 0

Well you can use basic validation like this:

```
{ 
  data: 'Attempts' ,
  render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
           if(data != 0)
           {
             if(type == 'display') {
              return '<a href="#'+data+'">'+data+'</a>';
             }
           }
           return data;
          }        
}
```

> How can I capture the 'SalesRep' name from the selected column?

The **third parameter** passed into the function is the data object for the whole row, while the **first parameter** is controlled by columns.data:

```
   { 
      data: 'Attempts',
      render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
               if(data)
               {
                 if(type == 'display') {
                  return '<a href="' + row.Attempts + '">' + row.Attempts + '</a> <a href="' + row.SalesRep + '">' + row.SalesRep + '</a>';
                 }
               }
               return data;
              }
    }
```

You can refer to below documentations:

https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

```js
var information = [
    { "Manager": "M1", "SalesRep": "Rep1", "Attempts": "1", "Completes": "91" },
     { "Manager": "M2", "SalesRep": "Rep1", "Attempts": "0", "Completes": "21" },
      { "Manager": "M3", "SalesRep": "Rep1", "Attempts": "0", "Completes": "31" },
       { "Manager": "M4", "SalesRep": "Rep1", "Attempts": "1", "Completes": "0" }
];

$(document).ready(function () {
    table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data: information,
        columns: [
            { data: 'Manager'},
            { data: 'SalesRep'},
            { 
              data: 'Attempts',
              render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        if(type=='display'){
                          if(data > 0){
                            return '<a href="#'+data+'">'+data+'</a>';
                          }
                        }
                        return data;
                      }         
            },
            { 
              data: 'Completes',
              render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        if(type=='display'){
                          if(data > 0){
                            return '<a href="#'+data+'">'+data+'</a>';
                          }
                        }
                        return data;
                      }         
            },
        ]
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Manager</th>
            <th>SalesRep</th>
            <th># Doors Knocked</th>
            <th># Sales Made</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This syntax is still setting a 0 value to be a hyperlink ```jquery
data: 'Attempts',
render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
 if(data) {
  if(type == 'display') {
   data = '<a href="' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
  }
  return data;
 }
}  
```

Comment: @HotTomales updated my code. If not working maybe you can show some part of data and i will prepare example demo to you.

Comment: I updated my OP.  Thank you again for the assistance.

Comment: And just in case it matters, on the database side of things, both fields are int(11)

Comment: @HotTomales the error causes when can't get return columns.data. Updated my code with fixes and added sample snippet to you to run